# How do you map recipes fetched from api's without id to a sql table's primary key id

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, database, api

I am using a recipe api from edamam.com.
When fetching recipes from the api i get json returned but when reading the data i noticed that the recipes comes without numerical ID. I want to be able to connect recipes to my sql table with primary key id's. How can I make this work?

I tried adding one recipe to the recipe table in sql and it went fine, it got the primary key id: 0.
But when trying to add the second one it complains on duplicate key, seems like it wants to add the second row with the same primary key id.

API response:

```
recipe
{
  uri: "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_2e9b699be433fab7da069629e1699455"
  label: "Easy Mango-Blackberry Smoothie Recipe"
  source: "Serious Eats"
  yield: 1.0
  calories: 274.59632724687503
  totalWeight: 537.5728540625
  totalTime: 3.0
  ingredients
  {
      text: "1 large ripe Ataulfo mango, peeled and roughly chopped (about 1 cup)"
      quantity: 1.0
      measure: "cup"
      food: "mango"
      weight: 165.0
      foodCategory: "fruit"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what is received from the api?

Comment: Yes sorry, I've added an image of the response now.

Comment: You need to find a natural key in the data, e.g. another field in the recipe that is unique. When you receive a new recipe, first check if it exists (using the unique field) and only insert if it does not. Then change the primary key to auto-increment, so you get a new id for each recipe that is inserted

Comment: Ahh Yes I see now! I cannot find a field that is more unique then the recipe name, so I'll have to stick to that. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the `uri` field includes a key value, which makes sense since the website must be able to identify the recipe from that uri.

Comment: Can you please provide the schema of the database table you are inserting the recipe into? If you have an identity specification on your numerical primary key, it shouldn't complain about duplicate keys.